# Math-like way to define a set in Python: technical name

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am learning Python properly for the first time and have encountered a cool piece of knowledge. Consider the example:

```
# list_dict is a list of dictionaries
keys = list_dict[0].keys()
out_dict = {key:[] for key in keys}
```

If my understanding is correct, the last line above creates a dictionary that has keys from `keys` and empty values. This line is also the first time I see a `for` loop used like a common way to define a set in mathematics using elements from another set (e.g. `X = \{x\geq 0: x in $\mathbb{Z}$\}`).

Is there a technical name for the way the `for` loop is used here?

I'd like to see more examples and learn more about it.

Comment: This is called a "dictionary comprehension". There also are list and set comprehensions (but _not_ tuple comprehensions).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes! As does ForceBru's comment above.